# Automapper - Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping with profiles

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, automapper

Hi there I am getting the error message
Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping. I am using a profile. Can anyone spot the problem?

Here is the profile class

```
public class ExampleProfile : Profile
{
    public ExampleProfile()
    {
        var map = CreateMap<ExampleModelSrc, ExampleDto>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.ExamplePropDest, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ExamplePropSrc))
            
    }

}
```

Example service

```
public class ExampleService : IExampleService
{
    private readonly IExampleRepository _repository;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;
    public ExampleService(IExampleRepository repository, IMapper mapper)
    {
        _repository = repository;
        _mapper = mapper;
    }

    public ExampleDto GetById(string id)
    {
        var result = _repository.Get(id);
        return _mapper.Map<ExampleDto>(result);

    }}
```

Starup class (ConfigureServices method)

```
services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup));
```

Is there anything I am missing? Cheers for help in advance!

Comment: You should let us know more about what AutoMapper- and .NET versions you are on.

Answer (score 2):

You need to register the profile, when adding AutoMapper to the DI-container in Startup.

`services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(ExampleProfile));`

Also, in your profiles, you should not put your expression into variable `map`. You should just call `CreateMap` directly without putting it into a variable: https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Configuration.html#profile-instances

Since you are handling cofiguration with profiles, you need to make sure you have this package installed: https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection/